# Jersey long running request times out

Tags: java, http, tcp, jersey

I use a Jersey HTTP server as well as a Jersey client for REST requests.

The client sends a file to the server, the server processes the file and returns a response to the client. My problem is, that the processing on the server can take several minutes, maybe even 1/2h.

I want the client to know if the request failed or succeeded in the response. However I set my readTimeout on the client to 60s because I read, that it's a bad practice to set it to 0. As a result I sometimes get a `SocketTimeoutException` on the client.

Is it safe to disable the readTimeout (set it to 0)? The connectTimeout would still be 10s.

Alternatively could I use TCP keep alive? As I understood it, this only sends those packets in large intervalls of dozzens of minutes (depending on the OS).

Is there anything else I could do instead of returning immediately with a token and then polling the server with the token if the processing succeeded? I read something about heartbeat packets somewhere. Can this be used?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you should NOT set the timeout too high, as that keeps the thread waiting. Having several requests would leave you with many a thread waiting and lead to the server jamming up.

Instead, if polling the server to see if the request is ready is not something you want to do,  I'd suggest you include a some kind of an identifier with the request, and have the server return the answer when its ready with the corresponding identifier included, then match the request and the response on the client side.

Comment: And how would I know when the server is ready? This would require polling again.